# хеш таблица в js

Tags: javascript, хеширование

Вопрос странный. Есть ли в js встроенная хеш-функция для хеш таблиц?
Искал информацию, не нашел.

Видел еще, что ассоциативный массив и хеш таблица это одно и то же

Разъясните мне что тут к чему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JS нет встроенных хеш-функций, поэтому, если вы хотите получить хеш объекта, вам нужно воспользоваться сторонними решениями, например md5, или написать свой алгоритм хеширования.

Ассоциативный массив - есть ничто иное, как хеш-таблица (без хеша) или мапа (без хеша) или словарь (без хеша). То есть, может хранить пары 'ключ - значение'.